# generate database from model classes

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ef-code-first

i am doing a project in asp.net with c# as the language and ms sql server express. i have four model classes so far:

First:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WerIstWo.Models
{
    public class Benutzer
    {
        //Eigenschaften
        private int benutzerid, gruppenid, urlaubstageinsgesamt, urlaubstagegenommen, urlaubstagerest;
        private string titel, bezeichnung, vorname, nachname, geburtsdatum, geburtsort,
            nationalitaet, strasse, hausnummer, plz, ort, land, mobil, fax, festnetz, email,
            homepage, benutzerart, status, benutzername, passwort;      
        List<Gruppe> gruppen;

        //Properties
        public int BenutzerID
        {
            get { return this.benutzerid; }
            set { this.benutzerid = value; }
        }
        public int GruppenID
        {
            get { return this.gruppenid; }
            set { this.gruppenid = value; }
        }
        public int UrlaubstageInsgesamt
        {
            get { return this.urlaubstageinsgesamt; }
            set { this.urlaubstageinsgesamt = value; } 
        }
        public int UrlaubstageGenommen 
        {
            get { return this.urlaubstagegenommen; }
            set { this.urlaubstagegenommen = value; } 
        }
        public int UrlaubstageRest 
        {
            get { return this.urlaubstagerest; }
            set { this.urlaubstagerest = value; } 
        }
        public string Titel 
        {
            get { return this.titel; }
            set { this.titel = value; } 
        }
        public string Bezeichnung 
        {
            get { return this.bezeichnung; }
            set { this.bezeichnung = value; } 
        }
        public string Vorname 
        {
            get { return this.vorname; }
            set { this.vorname = value; } 
        }
        public string Nachname 
        {
            get { return this.nachname; }
            set { this.nachname = value; } 
        }
        public string Geburtsdatum 
        {
            get { return this.geburtsdatum; }
            set { this.geburtsdatum = value; } 
        }
        public string Geburtsort 
        {
            get { return this.geburtsort; }
            set { this.geburtsort = value; } 
        }
        public string Nationalitaet 
        {
            get { return this.nationalitaet; }
            set { this.nationalitaet = value; } 
        }
        public string Strasse 
        {
            get { return this.strasse; }
            set { this.strasse = value; } 
        }
        public string Hausnummer 
        {
            get { return this.hausnummer; }
            set { this.hausnummer = value; } 
        }
        public string PLZ 
        {
            get { return this.plz; }
            set { this.plz = value; } 
        }
        public string Ort 
        {
            get { return this.ort; }
            set { this.ort = value; } 
        }
        public string Land 
        {
            get { return this.land; }
            set { this.land = value; } 
        }
        public string Mobil 
        {
            get { return this.mobil; }
            set { this.mobil = value; } 
        }
        public string Fax 
        {
            get { return this.fax; }
            set { this.fax = value; } 
        }
        public string Festnetz 
        {
            get { return this.festnetz; }
            set { this.festnetz = value; } 
        }
        public string Email 
        {
            get { return this.email; }
            set { this.email = value; } 
        }
        public string HomePage 
        {
            get { return this.homepage; }
            set { this.homepage = value; } 
        }
        public string Benutzerart 
        {
            get { return this.benutzerart; }
            set { this.benutzerart = value; } 
        }
        public string Status 
        {
            get { return this.status; }
            set { this.status = value; } 
        }
        public string Benutzername 
        {
            get { return this.benutzername; }
            set { this.benutzername = value; } 
        }
        public string Passwort 
        {
            get { return this.passwort; }
            set { this.passwort = value; } 
        }

        //Konstruktor
        public Benutzer()
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

Second:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WerIstWo.Models
{
    public class Gruppe
    {
        //Eigenschaften
        private int gruppenid;
        private string bezeichnung;
        private int anzahlmitglieder;

        //Properties
        public int GruppenID 
        {
            get { return this.gruppenid; }
            set { this.gruppenid = value; } 
        }
        public string Bezeichnung
        {
            get { return this.bezeichnung; }
            set { this.bezeichnung = value; } 
        }
        public int AnzahlMitglieder 
        {
            get { return this.anzahlmitglieder; }
            set { this.anzahlmitglieder = value; } 
        }

        //Konstruktor
        public Gruppe()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Third:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WerIstWo.Models
{
    public class Kalender
    {
        //Eigenschaften
        private int kalenderid;
        private int gruppenid;
        private int benutzerid;
        private string art;

        //Properties
        public int KalenderID 
        {
            get { return this.kalenderid; }
            set { this.kalenderid = value; } 
        }
        public int GruppenID 
        {
            get { return this.gruppenid; }
            set { this.kalenderid = value; } 
        }
        public int BenutzerID 
        {
            get { return this.benutzerid; }
            set { this.benutzerid = value; } 
        }
        public string Art 
        {
            get { return this.art; }
            set { this.art = value; } 
        }

        //Konstruktor
        public Kalender()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and fourth:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WerIstWo.Models
{
    public class KalenderEintrag
    {
        //Eigenschaften
        private int kalendereintragid;
        private int kalenderid;
        private string art;
        private string datum;
        private string status;
        private string kommentar;

        //Properties
        public int KalendereintragID 
        {
            get { return this.kalendereintragid; }
            set { this.kalendereintragid = value; } 
        }
        public int KalenderID 
        {
            get { return this.kalenderid; }
            set { this.kalenderid = value; } 
        }
        public string Art 
        {
            get { return this.art; }
            set { this.art = value; } 
        }
        public string Datum 
        {
            get { return this.datum; }
            set { this.datum = value; } 
        }
        public string Status 
        {
            get { return this.status; }
            set { this.status = value; } 
        }
        public string Kommentar 
        {
            get { return this.kommentar; }
            set { this.kommentar = value; } 
        }

        //Konstruktor
        public KalenderEintrag()
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

I read these tutorials to get this far:

http://webproject.scottgu.com/csharp/Data/Data.aspx
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

from what i understand, i need 4 steps to generate a database from model classes:

create models
create context class
create initializer
run application -> db is generated

but is it possible to do it without an initializer, or even without an context class? i thought along the lines of just letting vs generate a database based ONLY on my four model classes? or are context and initializer classes necessary?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use scaffolding, then that would generate everything as long as you don't have any many-to-many relationships. You can check this website to read on scaffolding http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/

Comment: thanks, i have set up mvc scaffolding...but i have still a problem, i get an error: Invoke-Scaffolder : "Cannot find a model type corresponding to a controller called 'Benutzer'. Try supplying a -ModelType parameter value" i think that it cant find my model class, it is in an extra model folder.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your project's folder/file directory tree?

Comment: A workaround would be to change the DBContext from DbSet<WerIstWo.Models.Benutzer> to DbSet<Benutzer>. This should solve your problem.